# При использовании асинхронного соединения с базой появляется следующая ошибка

Tags: python

Traceback:

```
TypeError: 'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
```

Вот сам код реализации соединения

```
class BotDB:

def __init__(self, db_file, pool_size=10):
    self.db_file = db_file
    self.pool = asyncio.Queue()
    for _ in range(pool_size):
        self.pool.put_nowait(aiosqlite.connect(db_file))

async def acquire_connection(self):
    return await self.pool.get()

async def release_connection(self, conn):
    self.pool.put_nowait(conn)

async def execute_query(self, query, *args):
    async with self.acquire_connection() as conn:
        cursor = await conn.execute(query, args)
        return await cursor.fetchall()

async def execute_modify_query(self, query, *args):
    async with self.acquire_connection() as conn:
        cursor = await conn.execute(query, args)
        await conn.commit()
        return cursor.rowcount
```

Comment: `async with await self.acquire_connection()` наверное?

Comment: Да, это действительно помогло